# PHP MySQL settings/configuration table calling values

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help me with this please.

I have a MySQL table called settings which I hold some config information (layout below):

```
+----+--------------+---------------+
| id | setting      | value         |
+----+--------------+---------------+
|  2 | partemail    | @example.com  |
|  3 | version      | 2.1           |
|  4 | altrowcolour | #ffeff0       |
+----+--------------+---------------+
```

Now what I want to do in PHP is a

```
"SELECT * from settings"
```

but have it loop through and assign the value to a variable so I can call those throughout the script but have the variable named what its called under the setting column.

so:

> $partemail would equal "@example.com"
>
> $version would equal "2.1"
>
> $altrowcolour would equal "#ffeff0"

So I have tried the below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM settings";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$config = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM config");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $config[$row['name']] = $row['value'];
}
```

but this isnt really working.

Can anyone help, apologies if the above is not best practise, I am no developer.

Thanks in advance for any help.

J

Comment: _"this isnt really working"_ means what exactly? (is the column name 'name' or 'setting'? The table name is 'settings' I thought, not 'config'!?)

Comment: *but this isnt really working.* Do you see an error message? The column is named `setting` but you read `$row['name']`  so it looks like you should use `$config[$row['setting']] = $row['value'];`.

Comment: To achieve the variable-names as you've described you'd need [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), but I'd recommend to stay with the array as you have it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you retrieve wrong column name.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM config");
$config = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $value = $row['value'];
    $setting = $row['setting'];
    $config[] = ['setting' => $setting, 'value' => $value];
}
```

**EDIT**

Using only mysqli

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM config";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $value = $row['value'];
        $setting = $row['setting'];
        $config[] = ['setting' => $setting, 'value' => $value];
    }
}
$conn->close();
```

you can echo the content like :

```
echo $config[0]['setting'];
echo $config[0]['value'];
```

Comment: mixing `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` functions and in general the use of the depricated `mysql_*` functions should be addressed too i think

Comment: Hi, thanks, that sort of worked but only for 1 setting.

Comment: All your setting are in the array `$config`. You can display all the contents by doing `print_r($config);`

Comment: Thanks, I just get "array" echoed when running a "print_r($config);"

Comment: Thanks but nothing is being echoed when I try to print the array or a specific item from the array

Comment: Manged to get it working, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Thanks, I am getting the content by using echo $config['version'];

Comment: I don't think doing `echo $config['version'];` will retrieve data

Comment: Yes I was surprised as well but it does which makes things a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your setting name is "setting", not "name"

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM settings";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $config[$row['setting']] = $row['value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The final code for others is:

```
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM settings";
$result3 = $mysqli->query($sql3);

if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {
while ($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()){
    $config[$row3['setting']]=$row3['value'];
}
}

echo $config['version'];
echo "<br>";
echo $config['partemail'];
echo "<br>";
echo $config['altrowcolour'];
```